# How to make a prepared statement with php variables and php array elements?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I know this is just some annoying syntax thing but i just can't get the code below to work.  Please can someone help?

```
if($stmt = $link -> prepare("INSERT INTO google_pre_transaction VALUES    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?")) {
  /* Bind parameters
     s - string, b - boolean, i - int, etc */
  $stmt -> bind_param("iiisss", 
  $m_id,
  $page_one['input-one'], 
  $page_one['input-two'],
  $page_one['title'],
  $page_one['first'], 
  $page_one['last']
  );
```

Comment: what does it do? "can't get it to work" is rather vague, help us help you.

Comment: You have alot more bind indicators than binds

Answer (score 2):

You have 13 `?` and 7 variables.  The numbers have to match.

Also, your closing parenthese is outside the quote, which is bad syntax.

This should work:

`prepare("INSERT INTO google_pre_transaction VALUES    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)")`

Answer (score 1):

For one, you have a lot more `?` then you have parameters in you bind_param. They should be the same amount.

I'm guessing the error is saying exactly that by the way.